# Mobile optimised website different zoom levels on different browsers

Tags: responsive-design, mobile-website, android-browser

Thanks in advance...

I've built a site that is responsive and has a mobile friendly version.

The problem I'm having is, on my Nexus 4, an iPhone, and most other Android devices I've tried, it displays fine...but on a Samsung Galaxy S2, it zooms right in and the layout is a mess.

I've got the viewport meta tag, I've tried the following, to no avail:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=480, initial-scale=1" />
```

All bad on the Samsung!
Can anyone see the problem and help it's driving me mad!
The site in question is dsimcockandson.com if you want to see the source.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Starting at line 1083 in your CSS you have:

```
.hide {
    display: ;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Is the missing value for the display property intentional?

Comment: Hi, not intentional no. It was for some elements that were to show/hide on media queries, I think elsewhere in the CSS it has a value? On a media query

Comment: I believe I removed any .hide classes from the HTML any where so this is actually never used